# Installing angular with/without -g in virtual environment

Tags: windows, npm, angular-cli

I created a virtual environment (Windows) using `python -m venv angular-env` and activated it using `angular\Scripts\activate.bat`. Now I am attempting to install angular into this environment. To install angular I need to run: `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

My question is this: if I add the `-g` (As I understand it: it means global), will it install angular inside of my venv or will it "escape" out of it?

I removed the `-g`, and I got some warnings and depreciation warnings.

Comment: Are you sure python virtual environments can handle JS packages ?

Comment: That's why I am asking.

Comment: Please share more details. What is your end purpose? Why are you doing it? Those 2 runtimes (python and js) are totally distinct and separated so I cannot see what you are trying to do.